# save multiple chkdsk logs to single file

Tags: batch, cmd.exe, chkdsk

I am creating a batch file to run `chkdsk` on every drive and log the output to a single file.

I am able to run a `chkdsk` and log it to a file with:

```
chkdsk a: > %userprofile%\desktop\test.log
```

However I am struggling to work out how to then run a new `chkdsk` and log that output to the same file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### How do I run a new `chkdsk` and log that output to the same file.

You need to use a different redirection operator.

The `>>` operator will append to a file.

Example:

```
chkdsk a: > %userprofile%\desktop\test.log
chkdsk b: >> %userprofile%\desktop\test.log
```

> **Redirection**
>
> ```
> command > filename       Redirect command output to a file
> command >> filename      APPEND into a file
> ```

Source [Command Redirection, Pipes - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [Command Redirection, Pipes - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)